# Python 3.x - Object not available in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, constructor

I'm having an issue with classes and passing an object to a second class, in the code below , the line `Class one` logs correctly to a log file and in class two the line `Class two print` outputs on screen but when it gets to the logger line in class two's default constructor I get the error below and the second line isn't written to the log file.

**Note: logger is defined and works ok in class one.**

Error:

```
NameError: name 'logger' is not defined
```

Code:

```
class one:

    logger = logger()

    logger.write("Class one")

    twoObj = two(logger)

class two:
    print("Class two print")

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger
        logger.write("Class two")
```

Comment: Where is `logger` coming from? Your code sample produces a`NameError` because `logger` is neither imported nor defined.

Comment: Exercise this lesson: [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: Please update your question with code which shows where this `logger` comes from. Also, which line does the error refer to? You should also update the question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are trying something like:

```
class demo_logger:
    def write(self, message):
        print(message)

class two:
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def demo_method(self):
        self.logger.write("Class two: demo method is called")

class one:
    logger = demo_logger()
    logger.write("Class one")
    twoObj = two(logger)

oneObject = one()
oneObject.twoObj.demo_method()
```

Output:

```
Class one
Class two: demo method is called
```

Comment: Sorted, my issue was I was calling `logger.write` instead of `self.logger.write`.

Answer (score 1):

works in such a situation.

try it:

```
def logger():
    print("\a")

class x:
    logger = logger()
    ....
```